# How to map my stored procedure returned values into my asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created the following stored procedure, which accept two parameters and search two different databases :-

```
Use ITSys
Go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvanceSearch]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @Name varchar(50) = null,
        @Tag varchar(50) = null
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select t.Tag , r.RESOURCENAME , rs.DESCRIPTION , tt.Name
    from [ITSys].[dbo].[Technology] t
    inner join
    [IT360servicedesk].[dbo].[Resources] r
    on 
    t.IT360ID = r.RESOURCEID
  inner join
   [IT360servicedesk].[dbo].[Resourcestate] rs
   on rs.RESOURCESTATEID = r.RESOURCESTATEID
   inner join
   [ITSys].[dbo].[TechnologyTypes] tt
   on tt.AssetTypeID = t.TypeID


    where t.Tag = @Tag and r.RESOURCENAME = @Name
    END
```

Then i created the following view model class, to map the stored produce values:-

```
public class AdvanceSearch
    {
        public string Tag { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string type { set; get; }
    }
```

and currently inside my repository class , i have the following :-

```
public IQueryable<AdvanceSearch> AdvanceSearch(NetworkAdvanceSearch na, NameAdvanceSearch nas)
        {

            var t = ITSys.AdvanceSearch(nas.name, nas.tag);
```

//map should be done here...

but i have the following questions:-

1. how i can map the values returned from my stored procedure into my view model class?
2. as this is the first time i work with Stored procedures inside entity framework , so is the way i am calling the stored procedure and mapping its values the right way to do things ? or there is a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: Normally the ADO.NET Entity framework would create wrapper class in C# for the stored procedure results. This I map it to the View Model.

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

1. do not use view models to directly get the data from the data store.
2. use domain classes or data transfer objects to get it. so in your case,

a. you need to hand-define the classes, if you use ADO.NET to run the SPROC and get the results.
b. you could leverage LINQ2SQL or EntityFramework, which help you with auto-generated classes to map SPROC results. (with EF, you might have to do some manual editing)

1. once you have the data classes populated by your repository, have the controller transform them into view models and render the view.

e.g. code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
 public virtual ActionResult Search() // take search parameters etc.
 {
  // this could be DTO or Domain classes or EF objects etc.
  IEnumerable<IDataTransferObject> results = _repository.AdvanceSearch();

  // you can do the transformation using extension methods, or linq to objects
  // or helper methods, or tools like auto mapper etc.
  IEnumerable<AdvanceSearch> model = results.ToAdvanceSearchViewModel();

  // return the view with the model data it needs.
  // this View Model is different from repository objects to keep the concerns 
  // separate.
  return  View(model); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but why i should NOT  use view models to directly get the data from the data store.?

Comment: also as i am getting the results from two databases , then i do not have a domain model which represents the results returned from stored procedure, that wy i created a view model class..